# Spring MVC - app with no default index page and textfield not showing

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

All,

A Spring newbie here.

I am trying to build a spring mvc(Sping 4.1.6 release) app. This app does not have a default landing page(like index.jsp, I have removed index.jsp from my app). This app will be called from another app by URL links or directly typing the path. My issue is I am not able to get this working. When I type localhost:8080/app/user.jsp(this is in WEB-INF/jsp folder) or localhost:8080/app/jsp/user.jsp(I would prefer not to use this path though).

Another question: I tweaked the app to have an index.jsp redirecting to user.jsp in the WEB-INF folder(not the WEB-INF/jsp) and the Controller @RequestMapping("/"), the user.jsp loads but the textbox is not displayed.

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>selfsrvc</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name = "suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user.jsp")
public class userController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(Model model){
        user user = new user();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        System.out.println("IIIIIIIIInside user Controller");
        return "user";
    }


}
```

My jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter your name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="user" /></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what I am missing in both the scenarios. Thanks.

**EDIT:** The suggestion by minion solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues or changes you need to do. Here is the Gist of the issue :

> Your spring servlet is mapped to / and the requested url is of the
>   pattern *.jsp. So it would never hit the controller that you wrote.

So change your controller to like one below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class userController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(Model model){
        user user = new user();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        System.out.println("IIIIIIIIInside user Controller");
        return "user";
    }
```

Use the url `localhost:8080/app/jsp/user` to hit the controller.

}